# I have 28 artisan custom commands. I want to make a single command that will keep on running all my 28 commands in a loop

Tags: php, laravel, command, laravel-artisan

I want to make a single command that will keep on running my 28 artisan commands in an infinite loop. I made a constant in which all commands are stored.

```
const CRAWL_ALL = ['run:command1', 'run:command2'];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Have you reviewed the [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling) documentation?

Comment: I know about the scheduling, I just want to make a single command that will run all my commands that i stored in an array as a constant

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to schedule your commands

Just edit this file `app/Console/Kernel.php` in the function schedule

```
/**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command(MyCommand::class)->daily();
        // As many commands as you want
    }
```

Check documentation for more details https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Dont forget the run command laravel that run schedule task

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: I know about the scheduling, I just want to make a single command that will run all my commands that i stored in an array as a constant

Comment: you can make one command that call another commands in one for each. calling like Artisan::call('my:command').  I advise you that run in background in one queue

Answer (score 0):

you can make new command to run all command you have, put all your command in array and call it with artisan facade class.

```
$commands = ['run:command1', 'run:command2'];
$max = $this->option('max');
$inc = 0;

while ($inc < $max) {
  $inc++;
  foreach ($commands as $command) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call($command);
  }
}
```

But i prefer using built-in laravel scheduler.